# TypeScript interfaces and union type arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose I have an interface like this:

```
interface Logger { 
  log(s: string): void; 
}
```

Why is the implementation `log(s: string | number): void {...}` acceptable in a class which implements `Logger`?

Comment: Because anything that calls that method with a string will work just fine. The fact that it *also* supports other types for the parameter is irrelevant to anything using it through the interface.

Comment: What if one passed a number?

Comment: You *can't* pass a number through the interface: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIHsDmnrIN7IBQyyANlgBQDOAXMlWFKJgJR0Bu6wAJgNxEBfQoQSk4VKsgDK6ALYQM2XMFkAHUhHnhJinFHzESZSvIlwcdBkxCZkAH2QgArrIBG0FgaPfkCdCCp0DQA6ckwKUypzCBZeQxIhIRF-Bl8xCV1oOhl5TP0AXkcIAHdpOQUsPQpY5ICwZFBIWEQKpSg6PORC0XEqPLiRdL7K6FDKACIYdHRxmsboeCQ8sfDJ6dmBnoyRqBWKACY58AWW5bCDmqA. Again, the support for other types in the concrete implementation is irrelevant to consumers of the interface.

Comment: Alright, I got it. So if one type-casts the instance of the class implementing this `Logger` interface back to `Logger` and call the log method, it will throw an error. The implementing class can have a `log` method which accepts broader types. Am I right?